# JPA + EJB: Transactions with Native Queries

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss, ejb-3.0

I have a problem with managing transactions with native queries in JPA in Stateless bean. I use JBoss EAP 6.2 and Oracle 11g database and as JPA framework I use Hibernate. Datasource is configured under JBoss with Oracle JDBC driver.
I have one method that should delete something in database and then update other entries in the same transaction. Below I have put simplified code to do this:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class MappingsDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    protected transient EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void updateMappings(int id, Set<String> ids) {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("DELETE FROM MAPPINGS M WHERE M.ID = :id");
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        query.executeUpdate();

        query = em.createNativeQuery("UPDATE MAPPINGS M SET M.ID = :id WHERE M.MAPID IN (:ids)");
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        query.setParameter("ids", ids);
        query.executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

When I executing this code delete query is executed and then update query  is intentionally failing to show that transaction not working correctly, but rollback in this case not working, because delete operation was not rollbacked.

I have also tried changing FlushModeType to COMMIT by adding following line:

```
em.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
```

but this also doesn't have any effect.
I have also tried using BEAN managed transactions and manually manage transaction but with the same effect.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why you are using native query, when you can simple write HQL query  in this case? Please, give more info about error, maybe stack trace.

Comment: The reason of using native queries here is to enhance a little bit updating process - less queries to trigger on database. I have reimplemented this solution to use entities and set up correctly cascades on that objects and now it's working fine. Problem with solution described here is that in logs, everything looks fine, but state in database is not correct. Thanks for your comment. It help me change my thinking about the problem, and try completly different solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One typical problem is that the PersistenceUnit is not JTA. You should mark it as JTA in both, your `persistence.xml` file and your JBoss configuration (DataSources).

Comment: Exactly. That was the issue. After updating datasource under JBoss to 'Use JTA', transactions start working correctly. Thanks!